# Why should I use HTML5 (context : placeholder)

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am an occasional HTML/js developer. Not that I want to say that I don't want to use HTML5.

Here's my situation:
No matter what I feel, the business requirement needs the behavior to be same across browsers (including IE). I can't use the "placeholder" in IE as it doesn't support it. In order to get over the limitation, I write a script which has `onFocus()`, `onBlur()` etc.

My javascript will check for `Browsers and Versions` and then emit appropriate code for `placeholder` if not supported.

Why don't I just not use `placeholder` when I have to write the javascript (for backward compatibility) anyway and it is making my javascript file lighter (by 1 line :)

Comment: Where is the question ?, What is the question ? If you want to support old browsers yeah you have to do some JS. If you don't care and to not which to do it then don't. That simple...

Comment: @3on I think the question is clear and valid ("Why use new technologies, when a fallback, which can also support new environments, must be provided anyway"). The only problem is, how to answer such a question objectively?

Comment: So you tag it with HTML5, to appear in the HTML5 questions listing, but you don't want to use HTML5? Oh, the irony. I also do not understand the question. Do you want to use a fallback only when the browser does not support the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute?

Comment: I didn't say that I don't want to use HTML5. My question is - If I do have to (to make it functional in old browsers) implement fallbacks (which work both in old and new browsers) why use HTML5 (placeholder) at all?

Comment: Sorry, but then you might want to edit your 2nd statement in the question which is slightly misleading: `Not that I want to say that I don't want to use HTML5.`

Comment: Oh never mind, I've read the first "Not" as "Note".

Comment: Now I see what Yoshi meant, this is hard to reply objectively. Honestly, web developers must push the web forward and not hold it back just because 0.01% of people use IE6. Force **them** to move forward and upgrade to a modern browser, they're the ones missing out what the web has to offer. Unless you're being explicit paid to make stuff work in IE6 then I'd abandon it. Honestly, whenever I'm doing heavy HTML5/JS development, I do include the [GCF](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) for any IE user.

Comment: I live in a more inhumane world where still the proportion of accesses from IE6 is 5% (GA says that). Thanks for the GCF tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is more of a subjective question but, in my opinion, HTML5 is definitely going to be the future. Eventually, things will come and go and there will be fewer and fewer people with older version of browsers, and it'll be more demanding that you know these options in HTML5 are available for you. It's simply good practice to implement both of them and not to disregard the other options.

Furthermore, while it might not be very noticeable in your situation, there are probably things that you can do in HTML5 which are much more optimized for the better browsers as opposed if you were to simply stick with the old fashion way of doing things. The difference in runspeed is probably not significant enough for someone to actually care that much but who knows? In the future, it could be something you're dealing with. I hope this answers your question.